# What is React Native's default line height?

Tags: react-native

I need to get some text's default `lineHeight` in React Native, when `lineHeight` hasn't been defined. I think it's normally about 20% of its font size. Does anybody know how React Native sets up its default line height?

Answer (score 5):

lineHeight is not calculated by percentage.

To give you an idea:

`fontSize: 40` use by default `lineHeight: 48`

`fontSize: 30` use by default `lineHeight: 35`

Unfortunately there is no rule that calculates it, but it is predefined according to ranges.

Comment: where i can look up those predefined ranges?